# how to show only unique item when append for my Cart View SWIFTUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

This are my code.
Im Creating Cash Register IPAD

What is see:
When I tap the item twice with the same item name it adds another
row instead

What I expect:
My expectation is it only adds one row of item and its quantity counter

Hope Someone can help me. I already research cannot find sample or any info to direct for what I want to achieved. Thanks all

[image: Screenshot on iPad]

```swift
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class OrderViewModel: ObservableObject {

   @Published var orderItems = [Cart]()
   @State var count: Int = 1
   
   func AddToCart(item: item){
         orderItems.append(
            Cart(product_name: item.product_name, price:item.price, quantity: quantity )
        )
    }
}


  struct Cart: Identifiable{
    
   var id = UUID()
   var product_name: String
    var price: String
    var quantity: Int
}
```

This are my cartView the will print all @EnvironmentObject  from class OrderViewModel

```
import SwiftUI

struct CartContainer: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var order: OrderViewModel
    var body: some View{
        ZStack{
             Color("lightGrayColor")
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                VStack{
                    HStack{
                        Text("Item Name")
                            .font(Font.system(size: 16, weight: .light))
                            .frame(width:200)
                        Spacer()
                        Text("Qty.").font(Font.system(size: 16, weight: .light))
                            .padding(.leading, -78)
                        Spacer()
                        Text("Subtotal.").font(Font.system(size: 16, weight: .light))
                            .padding(.leading, -78)
                    }
                }
                .padding(.top, 10)
                ScrollView{
                    VStack(alignment: .leading){
                        ForEach(order.orderItems, id:\.id){ list in
                            HStack{
                                 Text(list.product_name)
                                         .font(Font.system(size: 16, weight: .light))
                                         .frame(width:200)
                                     Spacer()
                                 Text(list.price).font(Font.system(size: 16, weight: .light))
                                         .padding(.leading, -78)
                                     Spacer()
                                Text("\(list.quantity)").font(Font.system(size: 16, weight: .light))
                                         .padding(.leading, -78)
                           }
                            .padding(.top, 10)
                    }
                    }.padding()
                }.padding()
                Text("Grand Total :")
                    .font(Font.system(size: 30, weight: .bold))
                    .padding(.bottom, 30)
                    .padding(.leading, 40)
                Button(action: {
                }) {
                               Text("Charge")
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .font(Font.system(size: 30, weight: .bold))
                                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                                .padding(.top, 35)
                                .padding(.bottom, 35)
                                .background(Color("ButtonGreen"))
                }.padding(.bottom, -10)
                          
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 550)
    }
}


struct CartContainer_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CartContainer().environmentObject(OrderViewModel())
  }
}
```

And this are the Product List which I pullout from API

```
import SwiftUI


struct ProductsListContainer: View {

    var body: some View{
        ZStack{
            Color(.white)
            VStack{
                ProductList()
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    }
}

struct ProductList: View{
   
    var body: some View{
        VStack {
            SearchItem()
            ItemListHeader()
            ShowItemList()
            .padding(5)
        }
        
    }
}

struct ItemListHeader: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            Text("Item Name")
                .font(Font.system(size: 20, weight: .heavy))
                .frame(width:300)
            Spacer()
            Text("Price").font(Font.system(size: 20, weight: .heavy))
                .padding(.leading, -78)
            Spacer()
            Text("Qty.").font(Font.system(size: 20, weight: .heavy))
                .padding(.leading, -78)
        }
        Divider()            
    }
}


struct ShowItemList: View {
    @StateObject  var itemVM = ProductViewListModel()
    @EnvironmentObject var order:  OrderViewModel

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(itemVM.item) { dataPoint in
                ZStack{
                HStack{
                    Text(dataPoint.product_name)
                        .font(.headline)
                        .frame(width:300)
                    Spacer()
                    Text(dataPoint.price)
                    Spacer()
                    Text("\(dataPoint.quantity)")
                }
                .padding()
                .padding(.leading, -20)
                .padding(.trailing, 20)
                .padding(.top, 5)
                .padding(.bottom, 5)
            }.onTapGesture {
                self.order.AddToCart(item: dataPoint.product)
            }
                Divider()
            }
          }
        .padding()
       }
   }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would help if you showed the code that displays the rows, how you call your addToCart function, and better explain the difference between what you see and what you expect to see.

Comment: @Abizern noted I will add in other code. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use "AddToCart(...)", you need to check if you have the item already.
Try something similar to this:

```
class OrderViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var orderItems = [Cart]()
    
    // note: comparing product_name, assuming product_name is unique here
    func AddToCart(item: Item) {
        if let ndx = orderItems.firstIndex(where: {$0.product_name == item.product_name}) {
            // already have this cart/item, do an update here
            orderItems[ndx].price = item.price
            orderItems[ndx].quantity = item.quantity
        } else {
            // add a new cart/item
            orderItems.append(Cart(product_name: item.product_name, price:item.price, quantity: item.quantity))
        }
    }
}
```

and probably call it like this:

```
.onTapGesture {
    self.order.AddToCart(item: dataPoint)
 }
```

Comment: yes this is good, I would suggest to increase the quantity and add-on the price in the function if the product is already in the cart  "orderItems[ndx].quantity = orderItems[ndx].quantity +1" and "orderItems[ndx].price = orderItems[ndx].price + item.price"

Comment: @workingdog thanks and its working now.  firstIndex() is missing piece.

Comment: Thanks All. You are all Awesome! now it's working for what I expected.  This save me a lot of time. Searching in google regarding this issue I have has no luck but here it helps me a Lot once again thanks